# windows10 and windows server 2012 nodejs catch Unexpected token in request data

Tags: node.js, json, windows, express, request

The code work fine in "macOS" without any problem but "windows 10" and "windows server 2012 R2"  get the error message.

I did try to encode `request` to utf8 but no help.

Please advise how to deal with this. Thanks.

**Code snap**

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const utf8 = require('utf8');
const iconv = require('iconv-lite');
const jju = require('jju');

...

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        const chunks = [];

        req.on('data', function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        req.on('end', function () {
            try {
                const body = Buffer.concat(chunks);

                if (!_.isEmpty(body)) {
                    req.body = jju.parse(body);
                }

                next();
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('incoming data:', err);
            }
        });
    });
```

**Error message**

```
incoming data: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '�' at 1:7569842
UUUlAC0lLRQAlFFLQAmKKM0ZoADSUtJQAtJS0nfFAC4ooooAbS0UtACUUUUAHPWg8��n
                                                                    ^
    at Object.parseJSON (C:\Projects\xxx\xxx\node_modules\jju\lib\parse.js:740:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\xxx\xxx\index.js:70:36)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  column: 7569842,
  row: 1
}
```

**update 1**

This error only happen when the `request` is large.

Comment: You really should use a body parser library instead of doing that `req.on('data')` dance manually.

Comment: i tried and still get the same error message. i use ```req.on('data')``` because i can use ```jju``` for better error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone who got the same problems, here my solution.

**I have solved this by using a Linux server.**